# Send intent from service to a broadcast Receiver and invoke a custom Dialog

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm continuously polling the server for response in service, at once the expected response comes the service has to send that response to a broadcast receiver, but I'm not getting any response from broadcast receiver, Moreover I wrote a Log in OnReceive method, which doesn't come in Logcat. Here in Service Code

```
public class BleepService extends Service{
String gotAlert;
Context context;

public static final String TAG = BleepService.class.getSimpleName();
int counter = 0;
static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
String resServer;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      
    doRepeat();
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void doRepeat() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {     
    new GetStatus().execute();

    Log.d("BleepService", String.valueOf(++counter));
    }
    }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}

class GetStatus extends  AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {           
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        resServer = sh.makeServiceCall(Urllist.urlGetPagerStatus, ServiceHandler.GET);
        while(resServer.equals("1"))
        {
        resServer = sh.makeServiceCall(Urllist.urlGetMsg, ServiceHandler.GET);  
        }
        return resServer;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("SERVICE", "COMES TO THE GetStatus AsyncTask Class");
        super.onPostExecute(result);        
        while(!result.equals("0"))
        {               
            Intent intent = new Intent(); 
            intent.setAction("DOCTOR_MSG_ALERT"); 
            intent.putExtra("msg", result);
            getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }       
}}
```

And the Activity which has the BroadcastReceiver is below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

IntentFilter intentFilter;      
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    errorRes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorResponse);          

     //Performing BackgroungTask with a Service
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BleepService.class));
}      


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("DOCTOR_MSG_ALERT"); 
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //extract our message from intent
            String msg_for_me = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
            customDialog(msg_for_me);               
            Log.i(TAG, msg_for_me);             
        }
    };
    //registering our receiver      
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //unregister our receiver
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
}  }
```

need a solution to fix it.

Comment: Solved by calling the Custom Dialog code in a Separate Activity